# yarn berry login to private npm repository

Tags: yarnpkg

With npm I login using `npm login --registry=https://xxx.jfrog.io/xxx/api/npm/npm-local/ --scope=xxx`
For some projects I have to use yarn version berry which does not use any npmrc file. So, I have to login to the xxx repo using yarn berry.
How should I loging to the private registry using yarn berry? I see it does not have any registry url argument

Comment: Did you find the according documentation to use yarn berry with Jfrog ?

Comment: I haven't, unfortunately